# Google Analytics Custom Metric not showing up in report

Tags: c#, google-analytics

In my admin page, I created a custom metric with scope 'Hit' and formatting type 'Integer'.

In my code, I'm making a web request to google analytics like so:

```
string url = string.Format("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid={0}&cid={1}&t=event&ec={2}&ea={3}&el={4}&ds=app&cm1={5}&z={6}", 
            tid, sDeviceID, eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel.Replace(" ", "_"), customMetric1, cacheBuster.ToString());
new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

However, when I view my report in Behavior > Events > Top Events > Event Label, I'm unable to select my custom metric under the 'Secondary Dimension' dropdown.

I also tried using a custom dimension, and I am able to see my custom dimension in the report dropdown, but when I select my custom dimension, there is no data being populated.

How can I filter my report by my custom metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view your custom metric you will need to create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) and select the custom metric from there. To speed up the process you can navigate to the Top Events report and then click the Customize button on the top left.